# Image display alters on some devices

Tags: php, css, image, mobile

I'm working on my mobile app [located here](http://www.xclo.co.uk/xclo2). Which has a link called "APP DOWNLOADS" which can only be seen on ios and android.

Now when viewing [this page](http://www.xclo.mobi/xclo2/apps.php?id=ipad) on my iPad the app image looks ok but when viewing [this page](http://www.xclo.mobi/xclo2/apps.php?id=android) on my galaxy s3, the app image does not look good. It is all stretch and thin.

The page is displaying the images by this code:

```
<img src="<?php echo $article['app_img']; ?>" class="appimg" border="0" border="0" align="left"
.appimg {border-radius: 30px;
  -moz-border-radius: 30px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    width:150px;    
    height:150px;
    position:relative; 
    background-color: transparent; }
```

But the browsers are obviously displaying different.

Can someone please provide me with a solution for this?

Screenshots available here:

> [iPad](http://www.xclo.mobi/xclo2/iPad.jpg) [iPhone](http://www.xclo.mobi/xclo2/iPhone.jpg) [Android](http://www.xclo.mobi/xclo2/Android.jpg)

All 3 of the above view the same code but display the image separately on the android.

Please help thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted it using this code

```
.appimg {
border-radius: 30px;
  -moz-border-radius: 30px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    width:150px;    
    height:150px;
    position:relative; 
    background-color: transparent;
}

@media only screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio:.75){
.appimg { 
 border-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px; 
    width:150px;    
    height:350px;
    position:relative;
    background-color: transparent;
}
}
```

Please 1up thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Even I had faced same problem not on xclo.mobi though.

And then I made the site dynamic , my css was dynamic based upon the current device.

So try to get current device and load css content on client browser accordingly.

Logic : if current device == ipad load css {width:150px}

It's because of browser and resolution of the device.

I hope  below code will help you more.

```
 <?php


/* detect mobile device*/
$ismobile = 0;
$container = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

// A list of mobile devices change as you wish
$useragents = array ( 

'Blazer' ,
'Palm' ,
'Handspring' ,
'Nokia' ,
'Kyocera',
'Samsung' ,
'Motorola' ,
'Smartphone', 
'Windows CE' ,
'Blackberry' ,
'WAP' ,
'SonyEricsson',
'PlayStation Portable', 
'LG', 
'MMP',
'OPWV',
'Symbian',
'EPOC',

); 

foreach ( $useragents as $useragents ) { 
if(strstr($container,$useragents)) {
$ismobile = 1;
} 
}
//And then you can load your css 
//eg:==
if($ismobile=1)
echo '.appimg{width:250px;height:250px}';//Change for device as you want
//After your php statements you can load your site content as usual
```

Hope this help you

Comment: See,s a bit complicated. Please can you give an example? There a lot of devices that I do not have to test on. Is there not just an if android then view this code?

Comment: My trouble is. As this is a web app it will only be displayed on all ios and android. Seems silly making it fit for all those other devices,

Comment: yup there is another way too , through js detect width and height of the browser and then change that accordingly

Comment: Please check my answer above and one up it. This sorted out my problem.